# Comparar valor diferente, valor "null" não entra no resutaldo

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela de arquivos, e nela existe um campo chamado "tipo_documento", que é preenchido com 1 ou quando não é preenchido fica NULL, o problema é que quando eu dou um `SELECT` e uso o comparador para retornar todos os resultados com o tipo_documento diferente de 1 `(AND tipo_documento <> 1)`, os dados que possuem NULL não são retornados, por que isso ocorre?

A forma que eu achei para contornar isso foi assim:

```
AND tipo_documento <> 1 OR tipo_documento IS NULL
```

Comment: O valor NULL significa que o valor dos dados para a coluna é desconhecido. Um valor desconhecido não pode ser comparado com outro valor. Use-se as cláusulas IS NULL ou IS NOT NULL para testar um valor NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Qual é o tipo do campo?

Era realmente para funcionar só com `AND tipo_documento IS NULL`.

Comment: É porque poderá ter outros valores, mas por que só o diferente de 1 não basta?